# Python Pandas - Strip Out Non-Numeric Characters and Spaces

Tags: python, pandas

If I have a pandas dataframe with column header "Name" and three rows (as below), how do I write a function to change the entries of "Name" such that all non-numeric characters, spaces and 0's at the front of numbers are stripped out to produce a new "Name" column as below?

```
Name (Before)
'John5'
'Tom  08'
'Ron 722'

Name (After)
'5'
'8'
'722'
```

Comment: Note I added a new answer on the duplicate question. But all the existing answers on the dup also look valid.

Comment: I think need `df['Name'] = df['Name'].str.extract('(\d+)', expand=False).astype(int)`